# js syntax passing name elements form validation

Tags: javascript, html

I just need help on how to pass multiple 'name' elements in my function that validates a form submission.

I have this and works fine.

```
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["FirstName"].value;
if (x == null || x == "")
{
    alert("asdf");
    return false;
}
```

tried this but didnt work.

```
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["FirstName"+"LastName"].value;
if (x == null || x == "")
{
    alert("asdf");
    return false;
}
```

Any help with the syntax on how to do so would be appreciated.

Comment: That won't work. You're looking for an element whose name is `FirstNameLastName`. What you want instead is to iterate over the child elements of the form.

Comment: @remyabel Any help with the syntax on how to do so would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying makes no sense.

```
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["FirstName"+"LastName"].value;
```

would get the value from an element called `FirstNameLasteName`.

So you probably meant this:

```
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["FirstName"].value + document.forms["myForm"]["LastName"].value;
```

Comment: ok thanks. anyway to group these name elements into an id etc then just have var x=document.forms["myForm"]["id"].value

Comment: got it working how i needed by replacing "+" with "&"

Comment: @user2912336 I'm glad that I could help you, however I don't know how. `document.forms["myForm"]["FirstName"].value ` **`&`** `document.forms["myForm"]["LastName"].value;` can't work to put string together. Are you sure you are using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You meant this:

```
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["FirstName"].value + " " +
      document.forms["myForm"]["LastName"].value;

       if (x==null || x=="")
       {
          alert("asdf");
          return false;
       }
```

Comment: ok thanks. anyway to group these name elements into an id etc then just have var x=document.forms["myForm"]["id"].value

Comment: Without seeing your markup I can't really say, i.e. it's not clear to me what you're trying to consolidate.